How do I efficiently set which code branch to use in a low-level C# function?
I'm writing a relatively straight-forward physics simulation, in which many small indicator points are initialized. The core of the code is in one project, with two different interface projects (i.e. two solutions) both using the same core.
The indicator points are instances of a class, Point, which is itself inherited by several other classes (to allow new properties and physics to be considered). Each Point has a location (x,y,z) and a The fundamental method in Point is Advance, which calculates the location update using the Runge-Kutta 4th-order (RK4) method. With many points this can become quite expensive, so for debugging and experimentation purposes I want to be able to switch to a lower-order method (e.g. simple first-order Euler integration, or perhaps a predictor-corrector method).
My question is: what is the most efficient way to handle this situation?
I've so far thought of three solutions:

Option 1: Declare a bool EulerUpdate at program initiation which is passed to the Point constructor (and of course to the constructor of all inheriting classes). This can then be used in one of two ways:

Option 1a: Set a private bool in the class, say UseEuler. Within Advance, check if UseEuler is true; if so, run the faster code. If false, use the slower, more accurate RK4 code.
Option 1b: Set a private function in the class, say UpdateCalc. Within the constructor, set UpdateCalc to either a method representing the Euler integration method (e.g. UpdateCalc = EulerUpdate) or the RK4 integration method (UpdateCalc = RK4Update) depending on the value of EulerUpdate. In Advance, just call UpdateCalc.


Option 2: Use preprocessor directives in Advance (i.e. #if EULERINTEGRATION) and then declare those in the csproj.

The problems I have with each are as follows:

Option 1: Both of these seem like they'll be slow because they involve either a) putting an if statement in very low-level code or b) doing some runtime shenanigans (polymorphism? I guess?). However, I do not know anywhere near enough about performance (in particular, performance in C#) to be able to comment sensibly.
Option 2: While this seems guaranteed to be the most efficient option, it comes with the problem that it would mean I have to recompile the core library for each interface. I'm reluctant to take that hit if I don't have to.

I'd be grateful to hear your perspectives on this; I've tried option 1 and found that it provided a serious benefit in run time, but I'm hopeful that I might both be able to do something better and to learn something more fundamental about writing efficient code at the same time. Thanks!

Problems like this are best solved by writing a Matlab script and then creating a dll that can be run from c#.

I would create a factory, that is responsible for an interface that contains the contract for advance. Then the factory just has to do something like "if(k4Count < performanceLimit) then you make more of the less performance methods, otherwise you make whatever more performance method you need.

May I ask what you mean when you say "low-level"? C# is decidedly anything but low-level...

@Dai - that's fair. In this case what I mean is that the method I'm trying to change is at roughly the lowest level of my program. So, at the top level, there's the configuration read-in, establishing the managers, handling input and output, and so on. There might be 2-3 "point managers", each of which might handle ~10,000 or more Points. Each of those points would then have their Advance method called a few thousand times during the course of a simulation, so in total this method will be called millions of times in a single simulation.

@MortenBork - that's an interesting idea, thank you! In this case I need to switch it for all Points because the choice is related to the user's goal (e.g. do they want an accurate simulation or do they want to quickly get a rough idea of the expected behavior).

Did you determine which method to use before testing?

The question is whether it is a good idea to have an Advance method in the point class. If you instead had a Motion class having an Advance(Point) method you could easily replace it with different implementations and apply it to all the points. The points themselves would not have to make the "branch".

Branches can be predicted by modern CPU assuming they are (statistically) predictable. Branches that are never taken are very very cheap. The one that are taken but predicted are a bit more expensive but still rather cheap (much more than virtual calls especially in real-world application and not simple benchmarks due to cache effects). The real issue is branches that cannot be predicted. Did you profile the code and show this was actually a problem?

Besides, you seems to use arrays of structure/class which are known not to be efficient on modern CPU architecture (this is far worst on GPUs). This approach tends to prevent any efficient generation of SIMD instructions (while physics simulations can often benefit from them when the code is SIMD-friendly). This is critical for performance since CPUs of mainstream PCs can generally compute 4x more double value with them resulting in a possible 4x speed-up (8x on Intel servers). SoA is generally far better than AoS in physics simulations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA .

In practice, due to C# (and OOP) overheads (e.g. object indirections, GC, etc.), it is not rare to see a 5x-10x speed up of simple arrays for each component (i.e. 3 array : x, y, z). You can still use class/objects and write a relatively fast code thanks to data oriented design. The game industry is moving away from the traditional OOP way of programming due its huge overheads on large programs (eg. AAA games). I saw the same issue on HPC simulations though people tends not to use often OOP in HPC simulations (especially physicists).

@JérômeRichard - this is helpful! Indeed, I'm using AoS/C, and based on your comments I fear I need to do a heavy rewrite. If I'm following your arguments correctly the branch prediction likely means that the performance I'm getting will be as good as can be expected given my current program architecture. I had done some profiling which broadly seemed to indicate this, but I wasn't sure if this was just due to the rather imperfect benchmark I used (plus I was hopeful to learn something new from the discussion). If you would be willing to convert your comments into an answer I'd be grateful.

"I fear I need to do a heavy rewrite" This is unfortunately often the case. Sometimes just the most expensive part of an application are sufficient though. Better sooner than later (It is not rare for people to learn such a thing several years too late and give up related performance benefits because of the huge maintainability costs).

"the performance I'm getting will be as good as can be expected" If the CPU can predict the outcome (i.e. not too random), then yes overall. The conditional check is not free but pretty cheap.

"If you would be willing to convert your comments into an answer I'd be grateful." I though it was not totally answering the question. Are you sure?

@JérômeRichard - yes, I think this hits the major beats. Honestly I think you answer the key question with the branch prediction comment - but I'd like to also capture your comment on AoS vs SoA. It feels particularly valuable because this is the opposite of the usual advice to leave performance improvements until later ("premature optimization is the root of all evil") - here, that thinking has left me with the need to do a lot of rewriting when it could have been avoided if I had avoided the temptation to start with a very OO framework.

@Skipsh You could use something like a Observer pattern, and then Dependency inject different "advance" interface implementations when the observer notices that it is time to notify it's monitors, thus making any class that has a "advance" contract, use that observer/monitor system, then the notify becomes a depedency injected "solution" to needing to alter all classes that has a composed "advance" method? Do I make sense?

@MortenBork Unfortunately this is beyond my understanding of OOP/C# - can you point me in the direction of some material I can use to better understand please?

Hi @Skipsh I will try to give a suggestion as an answer in the weekend. In the mean time google "Observer pattern" and  "Dependency Injection" those two sources should be enough to get you started
